# CSV is not converting in html using groupdocs

Tags: html, node.js, csv, groupdocs

I am using the GroupDocs Conversion Cloud API to convert a CSV file to HTML in Node.js. I have followed the code provided in the GroupDocs documentation, but I am not getting the correct HTML output from the CSV. Can somebody help me identify where the issue might be in my code.

```
const conversion_cloud = require("groupdocs-conversion-cloud");

let fileApi = conversion_cloud.FileApi.fromKeys(clientId, clientSecret);

let filecontent = "Name,Age,Email,Address John Doe,30,john.doe@example.com,123 Main StJane Smith,25,jane.smith@example.com,456 Elm AveMichael Johnson,28,michael.johnson@example.com,789 Oak RdEmily Williams,32,emily.williams@example.com,101 Pine Lane";


let uploaRequest = new conversion_cloud.UploadFileRequest('./spread.csv', filecontent);

await fileApi.uploadFile(uploaRequest).then(async (result, err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("upload- ", err);
    return res.status(500).send(false);
  } else {
    console.log("document uploaded", result);
  }

  let loadOptions = new conversion_cloud.CsvLoadOptions();
  loadOptions.separator = ",";
  loadOptions.convertDateTimeData = true;

  let settings = new conversion_cloud.ConvertSettings();
  settings.filePath = './spread.csv';
  settings.format = "html";


  convertOptions = new conversion_cloud.HtmlConvertOptions();
  convertOptions.fixedLayout = false;
  convertOptions.usePdf = false;

  result = await convertApi.convertDocument(new conversion_cloud.ConvertDocumentRequest(settings));
  console.log('CSV file converted to HTML successfully.');
  return res.send(data);
}) catch (error) {
  console.error('Error converting CSV to HTML:', error);
}
```

Comment: When you say "I am not getting the correct HTML output", what exactly do you get? Wrong output? Or is the error triggered (2nd last line)? What does the error message say? Also, it may be a copy-paste issue with your question here but the contents of the csv file does not seems properly formatted in `let filecontent = "Name,Age,Email,Address John Doe` etc., the lines now seem to be ended with space instead of a proper newline.

Comment: The output HTML that I'm getting is as follows:

</head>
<frameset rows="*,39">
  <frame src="/tmp/_files_files/sheet002.htm" name="frSheet"/>
  <frame src="/tmp/_files_files/tabstrip.htm" name="frTabs" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"/>
  <noframes>
    <body>
      <p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>
    </body>
  </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>

Comment: <p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>

Comment: Ya file content is the copy paste issue..

Comment: And which GroupDocs documentation page did you use?

Comment: Note that the csv file formatting may still be the problem here, if it is incorrectly displayed in your question here then it may also be incorrect in your actual code, which may in turn produce the problematic output.

Comment: I've rectified that issues in my code. but still facing same issue   
    

Name,Age,Email,Address
John Doe,30,john.doe@example.com,123 Main St
Jane Smith,25,jane.smith@example.com,456 Elm Ave
Michael Johnson,28,michael.johnson@example.com,789 Oak Rd
Emily Williams,32,emily.williams@example.com,101 Pine Lane

Comment: https://docs.groupdocs.cloud/conversion/convert-csv-document-with-load-options/

this documentation i m following

Answer (score 0):

Your reported issue is fixed in [GroupDocs.Conversion Cloud 23.10](https://releases.groupdocs.cloud/conversion/release-notes/2023/groupdocs-conversion-cloud-23-10-release-notes/). Please try the latest version of GroupDocs.Conversion Cloud SDK for Node.js.

## Convert CSV to HTML in Node.js

```
// load the module
var GroupDocs = require('groupdocs-conversion-cloud');
var fs = require('fs');

// get your appSid and appKey at https://dashboard.groupdocs.cloud (free registration is required).
var appSid = "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx";
var appKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

const convertDocument = async () => {

// construct Api
var convertApi = GroupDocs.ConvertApi.fromKeys(appSid, appKey);


try {
    const format = "html";
    const loadOptions = new GroupDocs.CsvLoadOptions();
    const csvContent = fs.readFileSync('Test_cust.csv');
    loadOptions.format = "csv";
    loadOptions.separator = ",";

    const convertOptions = new GroupDocs.WebConvertOptions();
    convertOptions.zoom = 100;

    const request = new GroupDocs.ConvertDocumentDirectRequest(
      format,
      csvContent,
      undefined,
      undefined,
      loadOptions,
      convertOptions);

    // convert document directly
      const result = await convertApi.convertDocumentDirect(request);
    console.log(result);
    fs.writeFileSync("CsvtoHTML.html", result);

} catch (err) {
throw err;
}
}

convertDocument()
.then(() => {
console.log("Document converted successfully");
})
.catch((err) => {
console.log("Error occurred while converting the document:", err);
})
```